# Is there a natural way to give a bisimplicial structure on a 2-category? 

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff

I mean by the nerve functor.

Given a 2-category $\mathcal{C}$, if we forget the 2-category structure (just view $\mathcal{C}$ as a category), the nerve functor will give us a simplicial set $N\mathcal{C}$. However, $\mathcal{C}$ is a 2-category, thus for any two objects $x,y\in\mathcal{C}$, $Hom_{\mathcal{C}}(x,y)$ is a category, applying the nerve functor gives us a simplicial set $N(Hom(x,y))$.

My question is, can these two simplicial set structure compatible in some way, gives us a bisimplicial set $N_{p,q}(\mathcal{C})$, say? Or is there another way to give a bisimplicial structure on a 2-category?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. This is called the [double nerve](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+nerve) of a 2-category.

See in particular the first reference cited at that link.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I can't open the .pdf file of the first reference. Am I the only one suffering from this problem?

Comment: I have added the arXiv link now: http://arxiv.org/abs/math.CT/0406615